# Unreal Engine Setup Fails

Tags: github, build, dependencies, unreal-engine5

Cloned Repository several times and tried everything. Fails every time. I never had an issue with Unreal Engine Setup before. I am beginning to think it may be due to Windows 11.

```
Checking dependencies...
Updating dependencies:   0% (0/97340)...
Failed to download 'http://cdn.unrealengine.com/dependencies/UnrealEngine-23448686/00bea197a7e321f427afb5898d135b353746bab8': InvalidDataException: The archive entry was compressed using an unsupported compression method.
   at System.IO.Compression.Inflater.Inflate(FlushCode flushCode)
   at System.IO.Compression.Inflater.ReadInflateOutput(Byte* bufPtr, Int32 length, FlushCode flushCode, Int32& bytesRead)
   at System.IO.Compression.Inflater.ReadOutput(Byte* bufPtr, Int32 length, Int32& bytesRead)
   at System.IO.Compression.Inflater.InflateVerified(Byte* bufPtr, Int32 length)
   at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.ReadCore(Span`1 buffer)
   at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.Compression.GZipStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at GitDependencies.Program.ExtractFilesFromRawStream(Stream RawStream, IncomingFile[] Files, SHA1 RawStreamHasher)Wrapped by CorruptPackFileException: Can't read from pack stream
   at GitDependencies.Program.ExtractFilesFromRawStream(Stream RawStream, IncomingFile[] Files, SHA1 RawStreamHasher)
   at GitDependencies.Program.ExtractFilesThroughCache(Stream InputStream, String FileName, Int64 CompressedSize, String ExpectedHash, IncomingFile[] Files)
   at GitDependencies.Program.DownloadAndExtractFiles(String Url, Uri Proxy, String CacheFileName, Int64 CompressedSize, String ExpectedHash, IncomingFile[] Files, Double HttpTimeoutMultiplier, NotifyReadDelegate NotifyRead)Wrapped by AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Can't read from pack stream)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at GitDependencies.Program.DownloadWorker(ConcurrentQueue`1 DownloadQueue, AsyncDownloadState State, Double HttpTimeoutMultiplier, Int32 MaxRetries, CancellationToken CancellationToken)
```

Tried Recompiling the gitdependancies solution, running as admin, checking all sdks and requirements in Visual Studio and rebooting several times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems Epic staffs are working on it.

[Upcoming Disruption of Service Impacting Unreal Engine Users on GitHub](https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/upcoming-disruption-of-service-impacting-unreal-engine-users-on-github/1155880)

Comment: Thank you. I searched all over for a solution and never saw that post. Would have made more sense for Epic to post that on their Github page where it was most relevant. Saw many users on Epic forum with same question but no answers which is why I posted here.